# How to find an equation that describes a non-linear correlation of multiple parameters

Tags: regression, correlation, data-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I tried to search for this problem but I don't know what exactly I'm looking for.

I found some empirical parameters that correlate but not linearly.
An example follows:
$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are the values that I need to calculate in the future, they were found through existing data analysis.
$X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ are the parameters that correlate with $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
I would like to create an equation that correlating these data in an approximate way:
$f(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) = (Y_1,Y_2)$

I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so please respond in a way that I can understand.

Comment: You may want to cross-post at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for *regression* or *fitting* of a data set to a function. (If you don't care about knowing $f$ analytically, look up machine learning). Hopefully I am understanding you correctly.

Usually, for numerical fitting, you pick a form for $f(X)$ and then computationally fit to it.
For instance, in Python, you could [fit a polynomial to it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)
or [some generalized linear model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.linear_model).
For general non-linear fitting (e.g. by [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)),
one can fit a function to the data by non-linear optimization, usually by least-squares error minimization (e.g. [in Java](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html)). Basically the parameters of $f$ are chosen to be as close to the observed $Y$ given $X$.

Then again, if you really want to compute non-linear correlations, I'd suggest looking at [rank correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), for example.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot.

Comment: I took a look at the options given but they seem to solve the problem when there is only one independent variable X, but I have 4 independent variables, so the need to find a function f(x, y, z, w)

Comment: Usually they can take $X$ as a vector of any dimension (maybe not in the first numpy case). The sklearn and java examples certainly do. If you really want a scipy example, I think [this one](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) works in higher dimensions (see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413217/fitting-3d-points-python)). The examples tend to be in 1d for some reason though.